# Visual Studio Code doubles search results with workspace and absolute path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently upgraded Visual Studio Code to version 1.36.1. 
Now I've got the problem that when I try to search a file it shows two results: one for workspace and one for the absolute path.

I'd prefer to have search results for workspace scope only. The same happens when searching files using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. There are few issues because of this; for example when I open the file from absolute path then 'Reveal in side bar' option isn't working.

Search example:
[image: search example]